# How to get array list at once

Tags: java, selenium, katalon-studio

In my console,could see below set of array list getting generated by loop (not at once)

```
    [09/25/2019, $221.03, 22,481,010, $218.55, $221.5, $217.1402] 
some output stuff ..
    [09/24/2019, $217.68, 31,434,370, $221.03, $222.49, $217.19] 
some output stuff ..
    [09/23/2019, $218.72, 19,419,650, $218.95, $219.84, $217.65] 
some output stuff ..
    [09/20/2019, $217.73, 57,977,090, $221.38, $222.56, $217.473] 
some output stuff ..
    [09/19/2019, $220.96, 22,187,880, $222.01, $223.76, $220.37]
```

how can i see those values at once in console/or log and importantly I need to get those values under table header

table headers are " `DATE   CLOSE/LAST  VOLUME  OPEN    HIGH    LOW` "

code :

```
ArrayList<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for(int i = 1 ; i<=18 ; i++){

        String abc = CustomKeywords.'nasdaqKeyword.accesstoTable.navigatetoGettablevalueFirstcol'(Integer.toString(i));          

         arrlist.add(abc);

    for(int j = 1 ; j<=5 ; j++){

     String abcd = CustomKeywords.'nasdaqKeyword.AccessToRestoftheTable.navigatetogettablevaluerest'(Integer.toString(i), Integer.toString(j));

            arrlist.add(abcd);

    }
    System.out.println(arrlist);
    }
```

Comment: I believe my Question is clear, i need to get those list array values at ones and show them under some table header values.

Comment: I have to agree with @TeaNG. I'm completely confused about what you are asking. Is the console output from Katalon Studio after running a test? Did you extract this information from a web page?

Comment: @GregBurghardt yes it is , please note that above console view is not getting at once and i need to get that at once.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need ?

```
System.out.print("DATE   CLOSE/LAST  VOLUME  OPEN    HIGH    LOW");
for (int index = 0 ; index < arrlist.size(); index++){
     System.out.println(arrlist.get(index));
}
```